# Link events on different pools

Tags: business-process-management, bpmn

Is it possible, by BPMN rules, to use link events to communicate between different pools? Or the only possible way is through message flow?

Comment: Congratulations to your first Stack Overflow question. You can do `bpmn` without any pools at all, like in the [BPMN Quick Guide: BPMN Examples → E-Mail Voting](http://www.bpmnquickguide.com/viewit.html). No code, no research, no explanation is just a useless shout out to the darkness. Can you elaborate on the problem you're solving? (after reading [Help Center > Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

The [BPMN 2.0 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/) elaborates on the usage of link events on pages 267 ff. (297 ff. in PDF).
While it does not *explicitly* state that link events must not be used to connect activities in different pools, some statements imply that doing so is at least not intended:

1. The spec stresses the role of link events as a substitute for **sequence flows**.
2. One of the examples is annotated as follows: "*Note that the figure shows two different printed pages, not two Pools
   in one diagram*"

Furthermore, *intermediate message events* (see spec page 251/PDF: 281) are the obvious choice when modeling communication between pools without using message flows.